# Android SDK manager

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk

So here is what i was trying to do. I was trying to create an android virtual device for eclipse, but i couldnt click ok button to create a AVD and i looked up online. someone says i need to install ARM AEBI System image thing. so i went to android sdk manager and tried to install the whole package. After i installed and i saw it said complete. i opened again the packages still showed up but this time i couldnt install anything anymore. then i tried to create a new virtual device, it still didnt work. What should i do? All i want is just import an android project i just wrote on eclipse and test it.
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

After installation you need to restart your IDE. While creating AVD you must select Android 6.0 as target Android version and then you can select armeabi-v7a as CPU type. Because the version of Android you installed now is Android 6.0. Try it again, hope it works for you.

Comment: after i restarted, i created a new AVD but the ok button didnt show up. i added a new picture

Comment: @DigitalMan You must be missing corresponded CPU/ABI for the target. Please check the installation directory or change your target.I think "OK" button doesn't show up because you are missing CPU type.